# Grep first group regexp

Tags: regex, bash, vim

Is there a way to specify what regexp group I want to append to my file?
In the example below I only want to store `(\d{8})` in my file:

```
grep -P1 -o kamilla(\d{8}) >> whatever.txt
```

Comment: Are the parentheses part of the pattern or are they an attempt at a capturing group?

Comment: @TomFenech It's a group

Comment: OK, so your input looks like "kamilla" followed by 8 digits and you want to capture the digits.

Comment: @TomFenech That is correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to use a Positive Lookbehind assertion or alternative so that it isn't included in the match.

**Positive Lookbehind**:

```
grep -Poi '(?<=kamilla)\d{8}'
```

The look-behind asserts that at the current position in the string, what precedes is "kamilla". If the assertion succeeds, the regular expression engine matches eight digits.

**Alternative `\K` escape sequence:**

```
grep -Poi 'kamilla\K\d{8}'
```

The `\K` escape sequence resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously matched characters are not included in the final matched sequence.

- `-o` option shows only the matching part that matches the pattern.

Comment: Is there an alternative to \K?

Comment: I trying to save the output in a text file but it store the filenames as well. Example : file1:31231213

Comment: I'm searching through all files in a folder and trying to save the output in a new file. Example grep -po1 [regexp] * >> hello.txt

Comment: Use the `-h` option to suppress this, `grep -h -Poi '(?<=kamilla)\d{8}' * >> results.txt`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-o` switch and a `\K`, which removes the preceding part of the match:

```
$ grep -Poi 'kamilla\K\d{8}' <<<"kamilla83222237"
83222237
```

As you're using Perl-style regular expressions, you could also just use Perl:

```
$ perl -nE 'say $1 if /kamilla(\d{8})/' <<<"kamilla83222237"
83222237
```

Comment: With `-o` – nothing. It’s the same as `-C 1` – print one preceding line and one following line to provide more context.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed it from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
$ grep -P -o '(?<=kamilla)\d{8}' <<< kamilla12345678
12345678
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` instead:

```
sed -E "s/.*kamilla(\d{8}).*/\1/g" input.txt >> output.txt
```

This is replacing input line with first matching group `\1` and printing it.

This also allows you to manipulate input file is some non-trivial ways. For example, you can match two groups and output them in non-default order, like `\2\1` and so on.